# Do $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x)$ exist if $f$ is concave over $[0, 1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, convex-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a concave function. We know that $f$ is continuous over $(0, 1)$. Is it true that both $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \uparrow 1} f(x)$ exist? Normal graphs of a concave function suggest these properties. But I have no idea how to prove them. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ must necessarily be defined to be equal to their respective limits when $f$ is concave on $[0,1]$?  That's a different question than asking whether these limits exist.

Comment: @BrianBorchers No, I am just asking whether the limits exist. I know that even if the limits exist, $f$ may still be discountinuous at these two points.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to match the actual question then.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize I used the wrong title.

Comment: Do you allow for extended real valued functions?  e.g. can $f(0)$ be defined as $-\infty$?

Comment: No. Both $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are just real numbers, not extended real.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \ln x$  does this function meet your criteria?

Comment: @DougM This function is not concave on $[0, 1]$ though.

Comment: @Ovi Isn't it?  The second derivative is always less than 0, and  $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \ge \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$ for all $(x,y)\in (0,1)$ and $\lambda\in [0,1]$

Comment: @DougM $\ln(x)$ isn't defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Hint: Consider the set of values for $f(0)$ that keep the function concave and then take the least upper bound on that set.

Comment: A concave (or a convex) function on an open interval has simple monotonicity properties. Either it's monotonic on the whole interval, or there is a point $c$ in the interval such that it's monotonic (nondecreasing on one, nonincreasing on the other) on each of the two subintervals determined by $c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Beautiful! Thank you very much. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is concave on $[0, 1]$ then
$$ \tag{*}
f(b) \ge \frac{c-b}{c-a} f(a) + \frac{b-a}{c-a} f(c)
$$
for $0 \le a < b < c \le 1$. This can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{c-b}{c-a} \bigl(f(b) - f(a)\bigr) \ge \frac{b-a}{c-a}\bigl(f(c) - f(b)\bigr) \, .
$$
In particular we have the following implication:
$$
\tag{**}
\bigl( 0 \le a < b < c \le 1 \text{ and } f(a) > f(b) \bigr)\implies f(b) > f(c) \, .
$$

Now consider two cases:

- $f$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$. $(*)$ with $0 = a < b=1/2 < c < 1$ gives an upper bound for $f(c)$, so that $\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x)$ exists as a finite value.
- Otherwise there is $0 < x_1 < x_2  < 1$ with $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$. Then $(**)$ implies that $f$ is decreasing on $[x_2, 1)$. $(*)$ with $a=0 < b < c=1$ gives a lower bound for $f(b)$, so that $\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x)$ exists as a finite value in this case as well.

A similar argument works for $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$.

It follows from the concavity condition $(*)$ that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) \ge f(0) \\
\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x) \ge f(1)
$$
(i.e. $f$ is [lower semi-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) at the boundary points) but strict inequality can hold.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This is @DanielFischer hint. One thing I want to add is that the (*) inequality also provides upper and lower bounds that are used to guarantee the limits are not infinity.

Comment: @user295959: Yes that is exactly Daniel's hint. I found it still worthwhile to demonstrate how it follows directly from the concavity condition (and I am sure that Daniel would have posted an answer if he had wanted). It becomes a bit simpler if one already *knows* that a concave function has one-sided derivatives at every interior point, and these are decreasing. – Good catch about the finiteness of the limits, I have added that to the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!